# How to use Linq aggregate with single quotes

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

Let's assume that I have a collection of strings, like so:

```
IList<string> myList = new List<string>(){"one", "two", "three"};
```

Using `myList.Aggregate` I would like to end up with "'one', 'two', 'three'" (including single quotes)

Does someone have a sleak way of doing this, only using the Aggregate function? I was thinking something in the lines of

```
myList.Aggregate((increment, seed) => string.Concat(increment, ", ", seed));
```

but that's only half the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any reason to use `Aggregate` rather than the simpler `string.Join`?

```
string joined = string.Join(", ", myCollection.Select(x => "'" + x + "'"));
```

(Add a `ToArray` call if you're using .NET 3.5.)

You *can* implement `string.Join` using `Aggregate` (ideally using a `StringBuilder`) but it's not terribly pleasant. Assuming a non-empty collection, I *think* this should do it:

```
string csv = myCollection.Aggregate(new StringBuilder("'"),
                 (sb, x) => sb.AppendFormat("{0}', '"),
                 sb => { sb.Length -= 3;
                         return sb.ToString(); });
```

Comment: I agree - using string.Join is a much better alternative :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you specify "only using the Aggregate function", how about:

```
myCollection.Aggregate(string.Empty, (soFar, next) => 
                       soFar + (soFar == string.Empty ? soFar : ", ") 
                       + "'" + next + "'")
```

(or)

```
myCollection.Aggregate(string.Empty, (soFar, next) =>
                                  string.Format("{0}{1}'{2}'", 
                                  soFar, soFar == string.Empty ? soFar : ", ", next))
```

Using `Aggregate` in this manner for string concatenation is  *really* inefficient though.

**EDIT**: Updated to get rid of the leading `,`.

Comment: I see your point - as I wrote to Jon I would probably use string.Join instead. Thanks for the example though.