# c# join string comma delimited, but double quote all values inside

Tags: c#

I have a string list

```
new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six" }
```

And I want to have a string with exact this content (including double quotes)

```
"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"
```

Because will write a text file that will be a array[] = { my_string }

I tried this with no success

```
var joinedNames = fields.Aggregate((a, b) => "\"" + a + ", " + b + "\"");
```

Little LINQ help will be greatly appreciate :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Linq aggregate with single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095480/how-to-use-linq-aggregate-with-single-quotes)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var joinedNames = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", fields) + "\"";
```

Comment: cannot convert string to string[] :)

Comment: Typed it from memory, had the arguments backwards. It's right now.

Comment: var joinedNames = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", fields.ToArray()) + "\"";
Thank you all of you!

Comment: That worked well for me. To print it in a Razor View, use @Html.Rar(Model.JoinedNames); // works like a charm!

Comment: Worked, but the escape char (the backslash) presents in the joined string. Is there a way to achieve this without getting the backslash into the joined string?

Comment: @JK If you're seeing a \ in the results, you're doing something different.

Comment: I don't think I am doing something different. In a bid to test this out, I am using the exact codes:
List<string> fields = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six" };
var joinedNames = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", fields) + "\"";
and I am getting the following value: "\"One\", \"Two\", \"Three\", \"Four\", \"Five\", \"Six\""

Comment: @JK How are you observing this? This could be an artifact of the Visual Studio debugger that doesn't reflect that actual string.

Comment: The actual value is inserted into database and I saw the \ in the database. I also observed the value while debugging in Visual Studio.. using breakpoint and inspect the value.

To further test this, I used the above code in my project too. (List<string> fields = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six" }; var joinedNames = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", fields) + "\"";)

Comment: @JK And you're sure you don't have a stray `@` character leading the string, or somehow a hidden extra \ to escape the escape character? Because your exact code works fine here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tfT9yS

Comment: I don't think so. To test this, I have the following two exact lines in my project.

List<string> fields = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six" };
var joinedNames = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", fields) + "\"";

Comment: The value for joinedNames, when you see it in the Autos window in Visual Studio, it is being shown with the \ chars. But, when you click on the magnifier icon and choose to show in Text Visualizer, the \ are not shown. Could this be the same for the test in dotnetfiddle.net?

Comment: Ignore the Autos window for this. It shows you the string as if you had typed it in code.

Answer (score 19):

You can do that easily with Linq and `string.Join`

```
var joinedNames = string.Join(", ", fields.Select(f => "\"" + f + "\""));
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `string.Join`:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six" };
var joined = string.Join(", ", myList.Select(item => "\"" + item + "\""));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six" };
joinedNames = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", list) + "\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<string>` is just an implementation of an IEnumerable interface, which int itself is a wrapper of and inherits the methods of `string[]`,  which has a `string.join(...)` method within it which is what you actually want to do.

I ran a test using your original data, however I added *null* within to the set. All 4 versions of the data (list, array, and an IEnumerable from each) performed the join method as expected and ended up with the exact same string.

```
    List<string> list = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", null, "Four", "Five", "Six" };
    string JoinedList = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", list) + "\"";

    string[] array = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", null, "Four", "Five", "Six" };
    string JoinedArray = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", array) + "\"";

    IEnumerable<string> ieList = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", null, "Four", "Five", "Six" };
    string ieListString = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", ieList) + "\"";


    IEnumerable<string> ieArray = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", null, "Four", "Five", "Six" };
    string ieArrayString = "\"" + string.Join("\", \"", ieArray) + "\"";

    Console.WriteLine("Joined List    : " + JoinedList);
    Console.WriteLine("Joined Array    : " + JoinedArray);
    Console.WriteLine("Joined ieList    : " + ieListString);
    Console.WriteLine("Joined ieArray    : " + ieArrayString);

    // results in
    //    Joined List     : "One", "Two", "Three", "", "Four", "Five", "Six"
    //    Joined Array    : "One", "Two", "Three", "", "Four", "Five", "Six"
    //    Joined ieList   : "One", "Two", "Three", "", "Four", "Five", "Six"
    //    Joined ieArray  : "One", "Two", "Three", "", "Four", "Five", "Six"
```

In the context that you presented, there is neither an advantage nor disadvantage  to any of the data objects. If we are looking for performance (however minuscule) were would want to keep it a string[], but if we need maximum functionality we would need to use List. The IEnumerable does have some added methods (eg Order) but does not have `Remove` functions (to catch that null value I inserted)

Comment: `List` does not inherit the methods of array and `string.Join` is a static method in `string`, not `string[]`.  Your entire first paragraph is nonsense.

Comment: @juharr So it could use some rewording,  do you have a recommendation?

Comment: While this answer does show how to quote and join multiple `string`s together using `string.Join`, its main focus seems to be comparing various data structures for storing those `string`s.  The author simply stated "I have a string list", and from the brief code snippet that follows we can't tell if it'd be appropriate to suggest another type.  None of this is "bad" information (though I agree with @juharr that the first paragraph needs some corrections), it just goes beyond the scope of the question and overshadows the answer to what was actually asked.